# How to Web Deploy a web application targeting Entity Framework 4.2 June 2011 CTP

Tags: .net, entity-framework, iis, webdeploy

I'm using  Entity Framework 4.2 June 2011 CTP in a small web application (ASP.NET MVC 3) because it supports enums.

I tried to deploy it using web deploy and I get the following error :

> The application pool that you are trying to use has the
>   'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application
>   requires 'v4.2'.

How to create an application pool running on .NET 4.2 ?

**Edit:** The web application does work with a 4.0 app pool so the real question is how to disable the app pool runtime version check when using Visual Studio Publish option ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526963/unable-to-correctly-set-managedruntimeversion-in-msdeploy-package

Add this to the web .csproj file in the initial `<PropertyGroup>` section:

```
<IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion>True</IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no .Net framework 4.2 out there, i would imagine the .net 4 sp1 is missing or you are not including all needed references. try installing sp1 on the server.

Comment: see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

Comment: wow it looks like they made another version of the .NET Framework then. A bit risky to use a CTP in a prod environment. If you have full control of the web server then you should install this CTP there are well and I guess you will be able to create an application pool which runs in this runtime framework. I would not do it anyway.