# Deploying failed in AWS Elasticbeanstalk - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-server-2012

I have a problem with deploying ASP.NET website on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I Tried to deploy from MS VS 2013, and keep getting

Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-WriteApplication1, Infra-WriteApplication2, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-PostAppDeploy] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null.

When i looked in the logs of the server

> AWSDeployment.log:
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.CreateApplicationRuleHandler.Update(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 132
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 51
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 66
>   2015-01-06 07:42:58,376 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Deployment failed: Unexpected Exception
>   2015-01-06 07:42:58,376 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [INFO]: Started Application Update
>   2015-01-06 07:42:58,376 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [ERROR]: Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception
>   2015-01-06 08:01:15,324 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Reading configuration from c:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\config\containerconfiguration
>   2015-01-06 08:01:17,771 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.ContainerConfiguration - Setting SiteName to 'Default Web Site'
>   2015-01-06 08:01:17,771 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.ContainerConfiguration - Setting AppName to '/WebSite1(1)'
>   2015-01-06 08:01:18,444 DEBUG 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.Container - Could not find application so returning the default application pool
>   2015-01-06 08:01:27,508 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
>   2015-01-06 08:01:27,508 INFO 1 DeploymentLog - Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
>   2015-01-06 08:01:28,068 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Exception during deployment.
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.
>
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.CheckAppPoolProperties(String appPoolName, DeploymentObjectAttributeCollection attributes, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String siteName)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.VerifyApplicationProperties(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.CreateApplicationRuleHandler.Update(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 132
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 51
>   2015-01-06 08:01:28,177 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Unexpected Exception: System.Exception: Exception during deployment. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.CheckAppPoolProperties(String appPoolName, DeploymentObjectAttributeCollection attributes, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String siteName)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.VerifyApplicationProperties(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.CreateApplicationRuleHandler.Update(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 132
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 51
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 66
>   2015-01-06 08:01:28,177 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Deployment failed: Unexpected Exception
>   2015-01-06 08:01:28,177 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [INFO]: Started Application Update
>   2015-01-06 08:01:28,177 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [DEBUG]: Could not find application so returning the default application pool
>   2015-01-06 08:01:28,177 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [ERROR]: Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception
>   2015-01-06 08:46:38,207 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Reading configuration from c:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\config\containerconfiguration
>   2015-01-06 08:46:38,707 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.ContainerConfiguration - Setting SiteName to 'Default Web Site'
>   2015-01-06 08:46:38,707 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.ContainerConfiguration - Setting AppName to '/'
>   2015-01-06 08:46:39,456 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Exception during deployment.
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.CheckAppPoolProperties(String appPoolName, DeploymentObjectAttributeCollection attributes, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String siteName)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.VerifyApplicationProperties(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.CreateApplicationRuleHandler.Update(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 132
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 51
>   2015-01-06 08:46:39,488 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Unexpected Exception: System.Exception: Exception during deployment. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.CheckAppPoolProperties(String appPoolName, DeploymentObjectAttributeCollection attributes, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String siteName)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.VerifyApplicationHelper.VerifyApplicationProperties(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.CreateApplicationRuleHandler.Update(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.deployPackage(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 132
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 51
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils.UpdateApplicationVersion(Container container, Boolean sync) in d:\Jenkins\workspace\mainline-cfn-beanstalk-tools\AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy\DeploymentUtils.cs:line 66
>   2015-01-06 08:46:39,488 ERROR 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Deployment failed: Unexpected Exception
>   2015-01-06 08:46:39,488 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [INFO]: Started Application Update
>   2015-01-06 08:46:39,488 INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [ERROR]: Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception

My Server is: 64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5

Hopefully someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I saw in cfn-init.log and found error:

> 2021-04-07 03:38:15,875 [ERROR] Command hooks (HooksExecutor.exe appdeploy\enact) failed
> 2021-04-07 03:38:15,875 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of Hook-EnactAppDeploy: Command hooks failed

Cause permission isn't cover deploying. please check permission.

Answer (score 0):

The key line here is:

```
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.
```

I was experiencing the same issue deploying a .NET 4.5 Web Application to Elastic Beanstalk, despite setting the application pool .NET version to 4.5 when I initially setup the deployment, and the fact that this deployment worked on non-EBS machines.

The workaround here worked for me.
[How to Web Deploy a web application targeting Entity Framework 4.2 June 2011 CTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365006/how-to-web-deploy-a-web-application-targeting-entity-framework-4-2-june-2011-ctp)